# Java POST data request returns HTTP response code 500

Tags: java, php, http, response

I am working on a program in Java that requires the user to log in, however when is end the HTTP request and try to read the output it returns HTTP response code 500.

The code in Login.java is as follows:

```
package net.discfiresoftworks.chat;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Login extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public JTextField user = new JTextField();
    public JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(20);
    public JButton submit = new JButton("Log In");
    public JButton create = new JButton("Sign-Up");
    public JPanel main = new JPanel();
    public JPanel buttons = new JPanel();

    public Login()
    {
        setTitle("DiscFire Account Login");
        setSize(350, 180);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(1));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(50, 50, 50));

        user.setColumns(20);
        pass.setColumns(20);
        pass.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 0, 10, 0), pass.getBorder()));

        submit.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY, 1));
        create.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY, 1));

        submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String password = new String(pass.getPassword());

                sendRequest(user.getText(), password);
            }

        });

        create.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

            }

        });

        buttons.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        buttons.add(submit);
        buttons.add(create);

        main.setLayout(new BoxLayout(main, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        main.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE, 10));
        main.add(user);
        main.add(pass);
        main.add(buttons);

        add(main);
    }

    public void open()
    {
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void sendRequest(String user, String pass)
    {
        String output = "";

        try
        {
            String urlParameters = "user=" + URLEncoder.encode(user,"UTF-8") + "&pass=" + URLEncoder.encode(pass,"UTF-8");
            URL url = new URL("http://www.discfiresoftworks.net/plogin.php");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();  
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
            connection.setUseCaches(false);

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            System.out.println(urlParameters);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            output = in.readLine();

            in.close();
            connection.disconnect();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String sid = (output.split(":"))[0];
    String admin = (output.split(":"))[1];

    System.out.println(sid = " " + admin);
    }

}
```

The code in plogin.php is as follows:

```
<?php

include 'includes/conn.php';
include 'includes/hash.php'

session_start();

if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){

    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];

    if(isset($_POST['redir'])){
        $redir = $_POST['redir'];
    }else{
        $redir = '';
    }

    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT Password, Verified, Admin FROM Users WHERE Name=?");
    $query->bind_param('s', $user);

    if($query->execute()){

        $query->bind_result($hash, $ver, $admin);

        while($query->fetch()){

            if($ver == "T"){
                if($query->num_rows > 0){

                    if(validate_password($password, $hash)){

                        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;

                        $msg = session_id() . ':' . $user;

                    }else{
                        $msg = 'Incorrect username or password';
                    }
                }else{
                    $msg = 'Incorrect username or password';
                }
            }else{
                $msg = 'Your account has not been verified, please check your email and do so now if you wish to continue.';
            }

            }

    }else{
        $msg = $query->errno . " " . $query->error;
    }

}else{
    $msg = 'Missing username or password';
}

echo $msg;

?>
```

Thanks in advance, I hope you can help me :)

**Edit: I know it is not a fault in conn.php or hash.php because I have used both of them before and they work fine.**

**Edit: Stacktrace:**

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://www.discfiresoftworks.net/plogin.php
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at net.discfiresoftworks.chat.Login.sendRequest(Login.java:116)
    at net.discfiresoftworks.chat.Login$1.actionPerformed(Login.java:58)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at net.discfiresoftworks.chat.Login.sendRequest(Login.java:128)
    at net.discfiresoftworks.chat.Login$1.actionPerformed(Login.java:58)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Is there a stacktrace from: catch(Exception e){            e.printStackTrace();
        } ?

Comment: There, I added it for you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved now.
Just check for correct encoding. make sure you have encoded everything to the same  charset.
in my case I am using ISO8859_1 encoding. the server was responding OK to firefox browser but error500 to my java program. I changed to ISO8859_1 and now it is working:

```
    public void sendPost(String Url, String params) throws Exception {


    String url=Url;
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    con.setRequestProperty("Acceptcharset", "en-us");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    con.setRequestProperty("charset", "EN-US");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    String urlParameters=params;
    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.connect();
    //con.

    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());
    this.response=response.toString();
    con.disconnect();

}
```

In the main program I call it like this:

```
    certcon.sendPost("https://www.desphilboy.com/authbox/generateCRT","csr_string="+URLEncoder.encode(requestparams,"ISO8859_1"));
```